# Symfony2 Forms: Custom field type that can accept both scalar and non-scalar values?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entities called `Organization` and `Person`.

I have create a custom field type named `OrganizationType` which I add under `PersonType`:

```
class OrganizationType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm($builder)
     {
          $builder->add('name');
          $builder->add('description');
     }
}

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm($builder)
     {
          $builder->add('fullName');
          $builder->add('organization, new OrganizationType());
     }
}
```

This works fine for this submitted data structure:

```
{
     "fullName" : "Justin Case",
     "organization" : {
          "name" : "FooBar Organization",
          "description" : "We do bar stuff."
     }
}
```

In my application logic, this will create two entities: The `Person` entity and the `Organization` entity, with their association persisted as well.

However, I wish to support **scalar** values in form of an identifier for the `organization` field, too:

```
 {
      "fullName" : "Justin Case",
      "organization" : 5
 }
```

The intended result is the `Person` entity is created, an an association to an existing `Organization` with ID `5` is linked and persisted as well.

However, it seems like a custom type can only support either a scalar value or non-scalar value, not both.

**What I have tried:**

I've experimented with attaching data transformers to `OrganizationType` (`$builder->addModelTransformer(...) and $builder->addViewTransformer(...)` both) in hopes that I can reformat the submitted data from scalar to non-scalar (or vice-versa) depending on what my custom type expects but sadly it doesn't work -- if the custom type expects scalar, passing in a non-scalar value will result to my transformers not being called at all. This is true for both view transformers and model transformers)

Is this use-case for the Form component supported at all? Or is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to append your data transformer to the main form (PersonType)?

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your `DataTransformer`. Can you attach that file? In any case, this is supposed to be handled by a `ModelTransformer` and not by a `ViewTransformer` at a first glance.